# In Stripe API - Facing error like Missing required param: amount

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

Stripe API, Trying to intergate in my code using cURL, But face the error. I am getting the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "parameter_invalid_integer",
        "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer",
        "message": "Invalid integer: <integer>",
        "param": "amount",
        "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_r1VgKFZTeHcKu1?t=1686081517",
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
$token = "XXXXX";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",                                                                               
"Accept: application/json","Authorization: Bearer $token"));

$data = array(
    "amount"=> (int)$amount,
    "payment_method"=>$paymentId,
    "confirm"=> "true",
    "confirmation_method"=>"automatic",
    "currency"=> "dollor",
    "customer"=> $paymentMethod->customer                
);
$jsonPayload = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonPayload);           
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);            
$output = curl_exec($curl);           
curl_close($curl);
```

I tried many ways, it shows error like amount is Invalid Integer.

---

UPDATE

I'm also getting the same error using Postman

[image]

Output of `var_dump($data)`

```
array(6) { 
    ["amount"]=> int(5000)
    ["payment_method"]=> string(27) "pm_1NGHfRSHUnJwHMxFxRyvs03T"
    ["confirm"]=> string(4) "true"
    ["confirmation_method"]=> string(9) "automatic" 
    ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD"
    ["customer"]=> string(18) "cus_O22SRWfvFRfVvE"
}
```

Comment: The content type should be `application/json`. I'm not sure if that will make a difference, though.

Comment: Have you tried going to the log URL to see exactly what they received?

Comment: Is `dollor` really an allowed currency? See https://stripe.com/docs/currencies for the acceptable currency codes, you're supposed to use 3-letter codes.

Comment: FYI: Note that the parameter `amount` is the amount the customer has to pay in [cents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/object#transfer_object-amount)

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks, In Log it shows like parameter_invalid_integer - amount
Invalid integer: <integer>. I changed the currency (USD), Still I faced that issue

Comment: @DarkBee, I noted, I passed the amount in cents, Still I have faced that issue

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump($data);` before encoding it to `JSON`?

Comment: @DarkBee I uploaded one image, Please check, I tried the API in Postman.

Comment: You're not sending JSON in the PostMan example.